# Find circle center from a segment of surface points

Tags: c#, algorithm, math, geometry

I need to find the center of a circle based on a number of surface measurements of a cylindrical object.

I currently use a simplified algorithm (written in C#) based on three points to find the center (taken from [How to determine the radius and center of a circle when only three noncollinear points are known?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2623673/how-to-determine-the-radius-and-center-of-a-circle-when-only-three-noncollinear)):

```
private Point CircleCenter(List<Point> points, double p1Skip, double p2Skip, double p3Skip)
{
    var p1 = points.Skip((int)(points.Count * p1Skip)).First();
    var p2 = points.Skip((int)(points.Count * p2Skip)).First();
    var p3 = points.Skip((int)(points.Count * p3Skip)).First();

    double mr = (p2.Y - p1.Y) / (p2.X - p1.X);
    double mt = (p3.Y - p2.Y) / (p3.X - p2.X);

    double centerX = (mr * mt * (p3.Y - p1.Y) + mr * (p2.X + p3.X) - mt * (p1.X + p2.X)) / (2 * (mr - mt));

    double centerY = (-1 / mr) * (centerX - ((p1.X + p2.X) / 2)) + ((p1.Y + p2.Y) / 2);

    return new Point(centerX, centerY, p1.Z);
}
```

The problem is that this method is very sensitive to noise. If one of the points is off, it will, of course, affect the center point.
I have 640 surface points available, for each cross section, and figure it should be possible to use much more than 3 points.

I'm guessing that the existing algorithm should be possible to extend with more points, but I can't figure out how.

Comment: Interesting Problem...3 points fixing a circle is mathematically correct, you cannot do much even you know more points lying on that circle. I think the direction should be how to reduce noise, or how to wisely choose 3 points out of 640 points to form a better approximate circle (circle center)...

Comment: One thought is to do a number of different 3-point calculations, using different points, and then calculate the mean or median of those points. I'm looking into that at the moment

Comment: Yes...similar thought (only concept, totally do not know how to implement), I think it sounds more feasible to "contract" 640 points into less points, say 320, repeat (and refine) each iteration, until ~ 3 points left and use that 3 point to form a circle?

Comment: First, define exactly what it is you want to minimize. For e.g. is it the sum of squares of distances of each point from the estimated circle? Then you can approach it as an optimization problem.

Comment: I improved my answer with your suggestion @samgak, it really improved the results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the help of my math guru colleague I've arrived at a solution using least square matrix calculation.

The algorithm used is described [here](http://www.had2know.com/academics/best-fit-circle-least-squares.html).

```
public static void FitCircle(IEnumerable<Point> points, out double x0, out double y0, out double r)
{
    setMklProvider();
    DenseMatrix A = DenseMatrix.Create(3, 3, (i, j) => 0);
    DenseMatrix b = DenseMatrix.Create(3, 1, (i, j) => 0);
    A[0, 0] = points.Sum(point => point.X * point.X);
    A[0, 1] = points.Sum(point => point.X * point.Y);
    A[0, 2] = points.Sum(point => point.X);
    A[1, 0] = A[0, 1];
    A[1, 1] = points.Sum(point => point.Y * point.Y);
    A[1, 2] = points.Sum(point => point.Y);
    A[2, 0] = A[0, 2];
    A[2, 1] = A[1, 2];
    A[2, 2] = points.Count();
    b[0, 0] = points.Sum(point => point.X * (point.X * point.X + point.Y * point.Y));
    b[1, 0] = points.Sum(point => point.Y * (point.X * point.X + point.Y * point.Y));
    b[2, 0] = points.Sum(point => point.X * point.X + point.Y * point.Y);
    var x = A.QR().Solve(b);
    x0 = x[0, 0] / 2;
    y0 = x[1, 0] / 2;
    r = Math.Sqrt(x[2, 0] + x0 * x0 + y0 * y0);
}

private static void setMklProvider()
{
    if (!_mklProviderSet) MathNet.Numerics.Control.LinearAlgebraProvider = new MathNet.Numerics.Algorithms.LinearAlgebra.Mkl.MklLinearAlgebraProvider();
}
```

This solution produces really nice repeatable results, at least for my data.
The `DenseMatrix` is a part of the [MathNet](http://www.mathdotnet.com/) library.

**EDIT**

To further reduce noise, as user samgak suggested, I added an iterative reduction approach that improved the accuracy:

```
double x0, y0, r;
FitCircle(surfacePoints, out x0, out y0, out r);
var center = new Point(x0, y0, surfacePoints.First().Z);

int reductionIterations = 10;
var reducedSet = surfacePoints;

for (int i = 1; i < reductionIterations; i++)
{
    var orderedByDistanceToCenter = reducedSet.OrderBy(p => (p-center).GetRho()).ToList();

    reducedSet = orderedByDistanceToCenter
        .Skip((int)(orderedByDistanceToCenter.Count * (i / 10f)))
        .Take((int)(orderedByDistanceToCenter.Count - orderedByDistanceToCenter.Count * (i / 10f)*2))
        .ToList();

    // Reduced to zero, abort
    if (reducedSet.Count < 3)
        break;

    FitCircle(reducedSet, out x0, out y0, out r);
    center = new Point(x0, y0, reducedSet.First().Z);
}

public static double GetRho(this Point p) => Math.Sqrt(p.X * p.X + p.Y * p.Y);
```

Answer (score 0):

(Would have left this as a comment but I can't)

I think the term you're looking for is "pose estimation". Have you considered using an iterative method like [RANSAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RANSAC) to find the best fitting model for your observations?

Answer (score 0):

If you know the points are uniformly distributed then the solution is very simple: average. You have a lot of points to make the average fairly accurate of the center.

If your points are not well distributed (i.e. you have a lot more points on one side of of the shape), then you can still do it but it's a bit more complicated. You can consider having a system of quadratic equations and you are looking for a point that minimizes the difference between the distance between each point and the center and the guessed radius. This is fairly hard math so you should try to find a library to solve it for you.

Comment: My points are not at all well distributed. They represent a segment of the cylinder. I.e. it is measured from one side. I've been considering least square equations and such, but like you say, the math get much more complicated.

Comment: I think I managed to do what you suggested. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction